# Gradient method using inverse of the derivatives

Tags: numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I often program with optimization problems, using well-known methods such as steepest descent, and conjugate gradient search. Now I am wondering a very simple rule
$$
x_i \leftarrow x_i +  \frac{-\mu}{ \frac{\partial f(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N)}{ \partial x_i}}, \quad \textrm{for } i=1,2,\cdots, N.
$$
where $\mu$ is small positive number (learning rate). Or we can write the delta of all variables by
$$
\Delta x= - \mu \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{ \partial x_1}{\partial f(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N)} \\
\frac{ \partial x_2}{\partial f(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N)} \\
\cdots\\
\frac{ \partial x_N}{\partial f(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N)} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The amount of the changing of $x_i$ is inverse proportional to the derivative $\partial f/ \partial x_i$. My intuition: A small derivative means the value of $f$ is not sensitive to $x_i$, thus one should make a big change on $x_i$ to improve $f$; Vice versa.

I programmed this rule and it works well(a relatively-complex function with 23 variables). Why such rule is not mentioned in textbook? I googled it without any relevant pages. Any comments on this simple optimization method?

Comment: You cannot divide by a matrix$\dfrac{\mu}{M}$, you should write instead $M^{-1}\mu$. It is a well know method called "vectorial form of Newton's rule".

Comment: \frac{\partial f(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N)}{\partial x_i} is a scalar.

Comment: OK, I understand. The method you are using looks to be the Newton's method.

Comment: @Jean Marie, Thank you! I read againt the wiki pages on Newton's method and gradient descent, and made a few tests. My observation is that: First, gradient descent is significantly more efficient than using the inverse gradient; Second,  although inverse gradient works,  it may be only reasonable for  single-variable functions.